# Forward server HTTP traffic to handle in another device via SSH Tunnel

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm developing some webhook required direct access public domain to internal machine, thinking use SSH tunnel to forward data, or got alternative solution?

Hosting server & development machine are in same network

```
 192.168.1.2/24 (Hosting server)
```

2nd machine is virtual mapping using forticlient firewall without static or dynamic IP in visible in hosting server, so is 1 way initial communication right now.

In this case possible to setup SSH tunnel forward all traffic from 192.168.1.2:80 to handle in development machine port 8080?

How to ssh syntax look like?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done by setting up an SSH tunnel to the remote machine:

```
ssh -L localhost:80:localhost:8080 development-system
```

Every request to port 80 on the hosting-server is now forwarded to port 8080 on the development-system.

Please note, that the port 80 on the hosting-server could only be used, when you start the SSH command as root. Also note that the port 80 is only accessible from the hosting-server. To access the port 80 on the hosting-server from everywhere use the following:

```
ssh -L 80:localhost:8080 development-system
```

Be sure that you want that.

A good introduction to the topic could be found at

- https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115897/whats-ssh-port-forwarding-and-whats-the-difference-between-ssh-local-and-remot